# Currying syntax in rust

Tags: rust, currying

I am trying to write a curried function in rust. According to [this](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/currying-in-rust/10326/3) discussion it should be possible, though it doesn't work for me.

For example this is an implementation of B combinator in java:

```java
static <X, Y, Z> Function<Function<X, Y>, Function<X, Z>> b(Function<Y, Z> f) {
    return g -> x -> f.apply(g.apply(x));
}
```

I am trying to do a similar thing in rust:

```rust
fn b<F, G, X, Y, Z>(f: F) -> impl Fn(G) -> impl Fn(X) -> Z
    where F: Fn(Y) -> Z,
          G: Fn(X) -> Y,
{
    move |g: G| move |x: X| f(g(x))
}
```

But getting the following error.

```
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` only allowed in function and inherent method return types, not in `Fn` trait return
```

Do I do it wrong?

Comment: I don't think that example works at all since it also has a `impl` keyword as the return value of another `impl` function which isn't supported.

Comment: Changing the second `impl` into a `Box<dyn Fn>` and a bit extra fiddling, and it can be made to work ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=80553946e81c74bc3f379319d3440ca9)).

Comment: Currying is converting a function taking multiple arguments into a sequence of higher-order functions taking a single argument. I don't think this is what you are trying to do here. (Not that it really matters for your question, but anyway.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach technically they're just saying they want to return a curried function though (aka returning a function which itself returns a function), they're not looking for a general-purpose currying feature.